# Android: Cannot load library (94 missing essential tables)

Tags: android, linker, android-ndk

I'm developing an Android application that uses a huge native library. Some customers are complaining about a crash at startup, one of them gave us his logcat dump:

```
07-19 10:55:15.139 E/AndroidRuntime(16539)FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
07-19 10:55:15.139 E/AndroidRuntime(16539)java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-19 10:55:15.139 E/AndroidRuntime(16539)at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
07-19 10:55:15.139 E/AndroidRuntime(16539)at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
07-19 10:55:15.139 E/AndroidRuntime(16539)at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
07-19 10:55:15.139 E/AndroidRuntime(16539)at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
07-19 10:55:15.139 E/AndroidRuntime(16539)at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
07-19 10:55:15.139 E/AndroidRuntime(16539)at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
07-19 10:55:15.139 E/AndroidRuntime(16539)at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
07-19 10:55:15.139 E/AndroidRuntime(16539)at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
07-19 10:55:15.139 E/AndroidRuntime(16539)Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
07-19 10:55:15.139 E/AndroidRuntime(16539)at my.app.appinit.NativeInitAsyncTask.doInBackground(NativeInitAsyncTask.java:86)
07-19 10:55:15.139 E/AndroidRuntime(16539)at my.app.appinit.NativeInitAsyncTask.doInBackground(NativeInitAsyncTask.java:44)
07-19 10:55:15.139 E/AndroidRuntime(16539)at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
07-19 10:55:15.139 E/AndroidRuntime(16539)at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
07-19 10:55:15.139 E/AndroidRuntime(16539)... 4 more
07-19 10:55:15.139 E/AndroidRuntime(16539)Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1935]:    94 missing essential tables
07-19 10:55:15.139 E/AndroidRuntime(16539)at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:434)
07-19 10:55:15.139 E/AndroidRuntime(16539)at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
07-19 10:55:15.139 E/AndroidRuntime(16539)at nativewrapper.NativeObject.<clinit>(NativeObject.java:30)
07-19 10:55:15.139 E/AndroidRuntime(16539)... 8 more
07-19 10:55:15.179 W/ActivityManager(162)Force finishing activity my.app.packagename/my.app.FirstActivity
```

The customer's phone model is Samsung Galaxy Ace (gt-s5830).
By digging on internet, I found this piece of code from the Android linker (http://source-android.frandroid.com/bionic/linker/linker.c): looking at it, It seems that zygote (pid 94) can't load the library for my application (pid 1935), I can't find any hint or a workaround to fix this, any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: "huge native library". What library?

Comment: Meaning that my proprietary library is quite huge (4.5mb) and has a lot of functionalities.

Comment: kind of a third party library or something you developed?

Comment: It's a not precompiled third party library, the source code is available to me and I compile it since Android 1.6, using android-ndk-r4-crystax in the past and android-ndk-r6 today.

Answer (score 0):

Update your application build with latest ndk release.

**java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError**

The exception occurs because the native library (DLL on Windows/ SO for linux) cannot be found. On UNIX and other systems, it can also be caused by a version difference between the run-time libraries on the system and the run-time libraries associated with with pre-built native libraries.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an error in your static block to "LOAD A LIBRARY".

Check these things

1. remove the "lib" from starting and ".so" from the end of the library name.
   for eg: if library is libTest.so

your code inside static block should be

```
static{

System.loadLibrary("Test");

}
```

1. Make sure you clean your project.